# sitecore search index with GUID value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I need to find a way to find the field value (GUID value) of results from Sitecore search index viewer.

Same thing when we click on Sitecore indexviewer and search for index in return provides a result with number of documents(fieldvalues and field name). Now I need to exclude all the fields which start with "__" and I need to exclude these fields in config file.

Please provide a way on how can I find the field values and the code on how to exclude fields values in config field.

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you are searching? Are you doing a FullTextSearch or a field based search with something like a WildcardSearch? Are you trying to search only a specific field in the index?

Comment: And provide us with details on WHY you have to do all of this through the use of a config file.

Comment: To find Field Guid go to template manager and select the template which has your field. Then expand the tree to find FieldItem and grab Field Guid from FieldItem's quick info section.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the way guids are stored, as short id's?

In most cases you should make sure guids are not tokenized during indexing and searching. (use keyword query and NO_TOKENIZE).